Make gt table search bar insensitive to accents
I'm working with an interactive table made with the gt package and I'm using the option for an interactive search bar with use_search = TRUE. My issue is that the search is sensitive to accents and I would like to make it insensitive to them.
REPREX
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)

days_of_week <- tribble(
  ~english, ~spanish,
  "Monday", "Lunes",
  "Tuesday", "Martes",
  "Wednesday", "Miércoles",
  "Thursday", "Jueves",
  "Friday", "Viernes",
  "Saturday", "Sábado",
  "Sunday", "Domingo"
)

days_of_week |> 
  gt() |> 
  opt_interactive(use_search = TRUE)

If I search for "Sabado" instead of "Sábado" (without the accent in the first á) then I get no results. How can I get rid of accent sensitivity?


AFAIK, this is not a built-in functionality of gt. So you need to write your own implementation.

Do you know any directions of how to write my own implementation?

There are some questions about filtering without considering accents in JavaScript and then other questions on how to use your custom scripts within gt. I don't have a clearer direction than that, sorry

I reworked this code based on your feedback. Since you mentioned, that you are building a quarto website. How about using custom js to place a new search bar over the exisiting one which then implements the custom search logic but is insensitive to accents?
---
title: "Interactive Table Example"
format: 
  html:
    page-layout: full
    code-fold: true
    
    header-includes: |
      <script>
      function removeAccents(str) {
        return str
          .normalize('NFD')  // Decompose combined characters
          .replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, '')  // Remove accent marks
          .toLowerCase();  // Convert to lowercase
      }
      
      // Create and inject custom search overlay
      function createAccentInsensitiveSearch() {
        // Find existing search input
        const existingSearch = document.querySelector('.rt-search');
        
        if (!existingSearch) return;
      
        // Create wrapper div
        const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
        wrapper.style.position = 'relative';
        wrapper.style.display = 'inline-block';
        wrapper.style.width = '100%';
      
        // Clone the existing search input
        const customSearch = existingSearch.cloneNode(true);
        
        // Add custom attributes to distinguish
        customSearch.classList.add('custom-accent-search');
        customSearch.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Search (accent-insensitive)');
      
        // Style the custom search
        customSearch.style.width = '100%';
        customSearch.style.boxSizing = 'border-box';
      
        // Insert wrapper and custom search
        existingSearch.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, existingSearch);
        wrapper.appendChild(existingSearch);
        wrapper.appendChild(customSearch);
      
        // Hide original input but keep it in DOM for original functionality
        existingSearch.style.position = 'absolute';
        existingSearch.style.top = '0';
        existingSearch.style.left = '0';
        existingSearch.style.zIndex = '-1';
        existingSearch.style.opacity = '0';
      
        // Add event listener to custom search
        customSearch.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
          const searchTerm = removeAccents(e.target.value);
          
          // Trigger original input's search
          existingSearch.value = e.target.value;
          existingSearch.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }));
      
          // Additional accent-insensitive filtering if needed
          const allRows = document.querySelectorAll('.rt-tr');
          
          allRows.forEach((row, index) => {
            // Always show the first row (header)
            if (index === 0) {
              row.style.display = '';
              return;
            }
      
            // Get all text content in the row
            const rowTexts = Array.from(row.querySelectorAll('.rt-text-content'))
              .map(el => removeAccents(el.textContent || ''));
            
            // Check if any text in the row matches
            const hasMatch = rowTexts.some(text => 
              text.includes(searchTerm) || searchTerm === ''
            );
            
            // Show/hide row
            row.style.display = hasMatch ? '' : 'none';
          });
        });
      }
      
      // Run when DOM is loaded
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', createAccentInsensitiveSearch);
      
      // Optional: Re-run if content is dynamically loaded
      if (window.MutationObserver) {
        const observer = new MutationObserver(createAccentInsensitiveSearch);
        observer.observe(document.body, { 
          childList: true, 
          subtree: true 
        });
      }
      </script>
---

```{r}
#| label: setup
#| message: false
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)
```

## Interactive Data Table (it works in the knitted browser version!)


```{r}
#| label: language-table
# Create the data
tribble(
  ~english, ~spanish,
  "Monday", "Lunes",
  "Tuesday", "Martes",
  "Wednesday", "Miércoles",
  "Thursday", "Jueves",
  "Friday", "Viernes",
  "Saturday", "Sábado",
  "Sunday", "Domingo"
) |> # mutate(spanish_normalized = stri_trans_general(spanish, "Latin-ASCII")) |>
  gt() |>
  opt_interactive(use_search = T)


```

If you run this (knit) in the browser, it looks like this:


Adding a searchable column without accents may be clever, but does not work if I pretend to hide the column afterwards with cols_hide().
Thanks for the shiny app suggestion, but is out of the scope of my application (quarto website).

Yes, I tried that too! Sadly, it seems like you can only search for what is shown. Why not just simply remove all accents from the spanish-column? Why does it have to be there?

Accents are an important part of the language

Agreed! Just keeping the searchable spanish in the table would have been the easiest approach. But I reworked my answer now, so that the accent-insensitive search works now if you knit your quarto website that is. Hope it helps. Cheers!
